# Android: how to make two screenrecord at same time?

Tags: android, shell, adb, video-recording, screen-recording

Now I make

```
adb shell screenrecord sdcard/video.mp4
```

It works with one device.
If I had two devices connected via USB running at the same time how could I start two video recording?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get your device ids :

```
>adb devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
7f1c864e        device
```

Then run your recording with :

```
>adb -s emulator-5554 shell screenrecord sdcard/video.mp4
>adb -s 7f1c864e shell screenrecord sdcard/video.mp4
```

As documentation says, you cannot save directly to your computer memory :

To begin recording your device screen, run the screenrecord command to record the video. Then, run the pull command to download the video from the device to the host computer. Here's an example recording session:

```
$ adb shell
shell@ $ screenrecord --verbose /sdcard/demo.mp4
(press Ctrl-C to stop)
shell@ $ exit
$ adb pull /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

Comment: thank you, do you know if it's possible to store videos dircetly into a computer memory? The computer cannot see the watch as a filesystem